# Specify host parameter for Node.js on Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

Most of my node apps I have been able to start like this:

server.listen(8080);

Now I am working with a phantomJS script which requires you to pass the host and port when starting the server. I have not been able to even get a simple hello world to work. I have tried to get the host value several different ways:
from a app.js file

```
   var hostname = require(‘os’).hostname().split(‘.’).shift();
```

from commandline

```
   uname -n
   hostname
```

And starting the server like this:

```
server.listen(8080,"127.0.0.1");
server.listen(8080,"localhost");
```

...etc
And the server starts w/o errors, but never responds to http requests. When I remove the host parameter it works fine.

node -v
v0.10.10

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:        10.04
Codename:       lucid
running in an ec2 instance
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this works as the host

```
0.0.0.0
```

If someone can shed some light I'll be sure to mark as answered, thanks for reading.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/228629 and http://serverfault.com/q/78048 should help explain it. And, [`.listen()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) also allows you to leave off the `hostname` to get the same result -- `server.listen(8080);`